# Why isn't this working when assigning a value to a zip in for loop?

Tags: python, zip

no variable assignation in a for loop when creating a zip

```py
x_coord = [23, 53, 2, -12, 95, 103, 14, -5]
y_coord = [677, 233, 405, 433, 905, 376, 432, 445]
z_coord = [4, 16, -6, -42, 3, -6, 23, -1]
labels = ["F", "J", "A", "Q", "Y", "B", "W", "X"]

points = []

for x, y, z, label in zip(x_coord, y_coord, z_coord, labels):
    # points.append(label + ":" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + "," + str(z)) #idea 1. working
    for point in points: #idea 2. not working. 
        point = label + ":" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + "," + str(z)

    for point in points:
        print(point)
```

I am learning a zip method in python. i need to combine those coordinates with labels in a certain format. i came up with 2 ideas but somehow second one doesn't work. i've been speculating over this but i have no idea why it's not working. i used print method to check what's going on in the for loop but it's not showing anything. Please help me get through this

Comment: There is nothing in `points` (`points = []`) so when you try to iterate over it (`for point in points`) nothing happens

Comment: `points` is empty at the time of iterating.

Comment: Okay, I read this more closely and... the question has nothing to do with the use of `zip` really, and is just about how to put things into a list. So I don't understand why it's confusing that the second attempt doesn't work - why would you expect to be able to put things *into* a list, by examining the *existing* list items (of which there are none yet)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without providing your expected behavior (please define "working"/"not working"), there's little that can be done here. You can edit the post to provide clarification. Thanks.

Comment: points is declared as list so you need to use append function not equal function

Comment: @Nick okay so if the list is vacant, you cannot use for loop to put assign new values? I guess idea 1 is the only solution then. thanks! i thought even if the list is vacant, by using for loop, it automatically generates virtual indexes.

Comment: @Dev oh okay. but even if i use append method, print(point) still doesnt show any result.

Comment: Correct. The for loop can only iterate over what it is given, in your first idea that's the zip object,  in  the second it's the points list which at that time is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use append function for list

```
x_coord = [23, 53, 2, -12, 95, 103, 14, -5]
y_coord = [677, 233, 405, 433, 905, 376, 432, 445]
z_coord = [4, 16, -6, -42, 3, -6, 23, -1]
labels = ["F", "J", "A", "Q", "Y", "B", "W", "X"]

points = []

for x, y, z, label in zip(x_coord, y_coord, z_coord, labels):
    #    points.append(label + ":" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + "," + str(z)) #idea 1. working
    points.append(label + ":" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + "," + str(z))


for point in points:
        print(point)
```

Comment: thanks for reading, but i wanted to check why the second one is not a proper solution.

Comment: you need to understand the list. using append to insert the value in the list. your solution is only applied for str function and it is only allowed to store one value at the time after second looping previous value will be deleted.

Comment: if you want to apply the second solution you need to declare str function instead of a list